# how to insert a variable in SQL which is already defined in the code

Tags: java

```
public class DB 
{
public static void main(.....)   
{  String str="hello";
    ....


st.executeUpdate("insert into r2( col1)  values(.....)"); // here r2 is the table in which i want to insert the "str" defined above.
}}
```

i want to insert this 'str' in the table r2 using the insert command.
 WHAT DO I WRITE HERE? TO INSERT VALUE OF "str" PREVIOUSLY DEFINED , how to pass the parameter 'str' from outside such that it gets inserted into the table??

Comment: which column of the table ?

Comment: wrong query.Column name is not given

Comment: Please read up about prepared statements.

Answer (score 4):

You will write it like this .. assuming column name in table r2 is col1

```
public class DB 
{
    public static void main(.....)   
    {  String str="hello";
        .... // Obtain DB Connection here
       PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert into r2( col1) values(?)";
       ps.setString(1,str);
       ps.execute();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to use a Prepared Statement.

Here is [Oracle's very comprehensive tutorial on using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

In your case (assuming the column you want to insert the value into is named "world") it would be done something like this:

```
String str="hello";

Connection connection = [...] // Set up connection

String queryString = "insert into r2 ('world') values(?)";

Statement statement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
statement.setString(1, str);
statement.executeUpdate();

// Add exception handling, clean-up
```

Try it and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Example {
   // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "username";
   static final String PASS = "password";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into table_name( col1,col2,col3) values(?,?,?)";
      ps.setString(1,str);
      ps.setString(2,str);
      ps.setString(3,str);
      ps.execute();
      }
      catch(SQLException e)
      {
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
      }
      }
```